# How to convert this CSS to SASS (arithmetics in selector)?

Tags: css, netbeans, sass

What is the best way to convert below CSS to SASS?

```
div#block-views-news-block,
div#block-views-news-block-1,
div#block-views-news-block-3,
div#block-views-news-block-4 {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

I tried this:

```
div#block-views-news-block {
    &, &-1, &-3, &-4 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
}
```

But NetBeans is returning me the following error:

> Unexpected token LESS_AND found.

Found one solution, but it looks not so good:

```
div#block-views-news-bloc {
    &k, &k-1, &k-3, &k-4 { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
}
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: I would surely want to know who have downvoted me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SASS looks valid and correct.  You can verify it at http://sassmeister.com/.

This seems to be a bug with NetBeans that was [resolved this past November](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246832).  You may want to try updating your IDE.

Comment: Thanks! :) One question though. I have latest and up-to-date version of NetBeans (8.0.2) but older build. Is there any possibility to update build version without application reinstalling?